# Prevent cgi/perl scripts to be executed

Tags: .htaccess, cgi, httpd.conf

Last week a server was hacked by uploading a perl script.
An uploaded .htaccess made it possible to run that perl-script (AddHandler cgi-script and Options +ExecCGI).

Is there a solution that +ExecCGI cannot be set through .htaccess?
Options and AddHandlers disabling alltogether is not a solution (used on other sites with other Handlers/Options)

Another thing to solve it:
Allow only specific-files (formail.cgi, awstats.pl) to be executed by CGI (specified in httpd.conf)
Is this in someway possible?

Answer (score 0):

If figured it out myself (RTFM!)

This line in http.conf will stop enabling ExecCGI by an .htaccess-file:

AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=FollowSymLinks,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch